# How to list all roots directories with Powershell

Tags: powershell

With the tree command, I can see the tree structure of my root directoy.
But I can't see if there are other root directory and what is their name.

Is there a command to find them?

Comment: So you want the "sibling" directories of a given other directory?

Comment: Yes, that exactly what I want

Comment: `Get-Item C:\some\path |Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath { $_.Parent.FullName } -Directory`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen  I've tried with  Get-Item C:\ |Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath { $_.Parent.FullName } -Directory  . It doesn't work: Get-ChildItem : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'LiteralPath' because it is null.  I should get at least one result :C\

Comment: ```C:\``` is the volume root, there's no "deeper" you can go. If you want to enumerate all volumes, use `Get-PSDrive`